# ideal Partition and System bootup time

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 16.04, partitioning, filesystem

A few months back, I installed Ubuntu 16.04 lts alongside windows 10 on my laptop.

Of late my boot up time has considerably increased to well over a minute and searching on the internet for solutions led me to believe that i might not have given a good partition.can somebody look into this and help me find a solution?

My laptop is a dell inspiron 3537.

I used this command to display partition details of my dual boot

```
$ sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL

NAME    FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda            931.5G

├─sda1  vfat     500M /boot/efi  ESP
├─sda2  vfat      40M            DIAGS
├─sda3           128M             
├─sda4  ntfs     490M            WINRETOOLS
├─sda5  ntfs   164.7G            system
├─sda6  ntfs     450M            
├─sda7  ntfs   102.4G            Softwares
├─sda8  ntfs   100.7G            media
├─sda9  ntfs    11.7G            PBR Image
├─sda10 ext4     284G / 
└─sda11 swap     5.9G [SWAP] 

sr0             1024M
```

I used the `systemd-analyze blame` and this is the output

```
       9.688s apparmor.service
       8.298s dev-sda10.device
       7.201s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3485\x2dF3E2.service
       5.349s plymouth-read-write.service
       3.618s NetworkManager.service
       3.474s snapd.firstboot.service
       3.295s ModemManager.service
       3.180s accounts-daemon.service
       2.793s grub-common.service
       2.412s plymouth-start.service
       2.388s thermald.service
       2.247s systemd-udevd.service
       1.716s polkitd.service
       1.562s lightdm.service
       1.538s keyboard-setup.service
       1.471s systemd-logind.service
       1.469s gpu-manager.service
       1.343s upower.service
       1.254s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
       1.247s systemd-modules-load.service
       1.202s console-setup.service
        954ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
        898ms systemd-journald.service
```

Prior to all this I also removed some older kernels based on suggestions from the internet.

This is my kernel version now

```
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic           4.4.0-38.57 amd64  
Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP rc
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic         4.4.0-21.37   amd64
Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP rc 
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic         4.4.0-31.50  amd64
Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP ii
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-38-generic         4.4.0-38.57  amd64
Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP ii
linux-image-generic                        4.4.0.38.40  amd64
Generic Linux kernel image
```

Comment: Not sure this has anything to do with partition. There is, obviously, no ideal way to do partitions.

Comment: @mikewhatever New to ubuntu,so had my doubts about the partitions.